# Integration of generating function

Tags: integration, power-series, generating-functions

I am trying to integrate a generating function.

On the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Differentiation_and_integration_of_generating_functions) page for Generating Functions, the section "Differentiation and integration of generating functions" states:
$$
G^{\prime}(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} (n+1) g_{n+1} z^n \\ 
z \cdot G^{\prime}(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} n g_{n} z^n \\ 
\int_0^z G(t) dt = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{g_{n-1}}{n} z^n
$$

However, it is unclear to me how to calculate $g_{n-1}$ or what $g_{n-1}$ is. I would like to be able to integrate the following:

$$
G(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

But I am unclear on how to do so using the statements above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: $g_{n-1}$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $G(x)$. That's convention.

Comment: Ok.. So how would I use this to integrate the exponential generating function (written above: $G(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$)?

Comment: I don't want to provide full answer, just a hint. First, can you calculate coefficient of $x^n$ of $G(x)$? Then you just need to plug the value into the third formula above and get the answer.

Comment: This is not for a school assignment. This is for a personal project I am working on. I would appreciate a full answer with steps so I can learn most clearly and quickly. Thank you. Additionally, I don't have extensive math knowledge, so an explanation in laymans terms would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$$G(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$\begin{array}{ll}
  \int G(x) d x && = \int ( \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} ) dx \\
  && = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} (\int  \frac{x^n}{n!} dx) \\
  && = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac {\int  x^n dx} {n!}) && \text{because of linearity of integration} \\
  && = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac {x^{n+1}} {n!(n+1)}) && \text{by the definition of }\int  x^n dx\\
  && = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n+1}} {(n+1)!} \\
  && = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n} {n!} \\
\end{array}
$$

Alternatively, write $$G(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} g_n {x^n}$$ by convention, we have
$$ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{n!}\times x^n \right) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} g_n {x^n} $$, thus $g_n = \frac 1 {n!}$ .

Applying to the formula, we have

$$ \int G(x) d x = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{g_{n-1}}{n} = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{(n-1)!}}{n} = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)!}= \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

which gives the same result.

In conclusion, integration of a generating function is not different from that of normal function.